# trying to use a function that return a button component but nothing get rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use a function that return a button component but when calling this function, the button component didn't render. Everything rendered except this function. I have no errors no warnings and i have tried to separate this function in a separate file but still no rendering for that function. 
I am using react-bootstrap. the function i am trying to call is activeProcessingBtn

```
const activeProcessingBtn = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="primary" disabled>
        <Spinner
          as="span"
          animation="grow"
          size="sm"
          role="status"
          aria-hidden="true"
        />
        processing...
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
function Machines() {
  const [machineInfo, setMachineInfo] = useState({
    id: 0,
    name: "Choose Machine"
  });
  const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = useState(true);

  const Machiness = [
    { id: 1, name: "Machine1" },
    { id: 2, name: "Machine2" },
    { id: 3, name: "Machine3" }
  ];

  const selectHandler = (NewName, NewID) => {
    setMachineInfo({ id: NewID, name: NewName });
  };

  const AddMachinesToDropDownItem = Machiness.map(({ id, name }) => {
    return (
      <Dropdown.Item
        eventKey={id}
        value={name}
        className="DropdownItem"
        onClick={() => selectHandler(name, id)}
      >
        {name}
      </Dropdown.Item>
    );
  });


  return (
    <div>
      <h6> Get attendance Manually </h6>
      <DropdownButton id="DropDownMenu" title={machineInfo.name}>
        {AddMachinesToDropDownItem}
      </DropdownButton>

      <activeProcessingBtn />

    </div>
  );
}

export default Machines;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All component names should start with an uppercase letter. This is what React uses to figure out whether it should consider an element a native HTML element and pass it over to the browser or further resolve what it renders. So your best option would be to rename the function to `ActiveProcessingBtn` or `ActiveProcessingButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to treat it like a component (`<activeProcessingBtn />`), call it as a function.

```
return (
  <div>
    <h6> Get attendance Manually </h6>
    <DropdownButton id="DropDownMenu" title={machineInfo.name}>
      {AddMachinesToDropDownItem}
    </DropdownButton>

    // See here
    {activeProcessingBtn()}

  </div>
);
```